# How do I modify the <title> tag on my Category Archive page?

Tags: headers, wp-head

I'm using the 2016 template and it uses wp_head() to render the title tag. So for Category pages it displays

```
 Articles about: whatever
```

How do I modify this?

EDIT: I ended up doing this hack. Which I hate...

```
remove_action( 'wp_head', '_wp_render_title_tag', 1 );
add_action( 'wp_head', '_wp_render_title_tag_jch', 1 );

function _wp_render_title_tag_jch() {
    if ( did_action( 'wp_head' ) || doing_action( 'wp_head' ) ) {     
       $t = wp_get_document_title();
       if( strpos($t, 'Weekly Updates',0) >= 0 )
          echo( '<title>' . 'Weekly Updates - Example Site' . '</title>' . "\n");
        else
          echo( '<title>' . $t . '</title>' . "\n");              
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The default WordPress themes such as Twenty Sixteen and Twenty Twenty-One are using the [automatic `<title>` tag feature (or the `title-tag` theme support) introduced in WordPress 4.1](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2014/10/29/title-tags-in-4-1/), so with that feature, if you want to modify the title, you would want to use the [`document_title_parts` hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/document_title_parts/):

```php
add_filter( 'document_title_parts', 'my_document_title_parts' );
function my_document_title_parts( $title ) { // $title is an *array*
    if ( is_category() ) {
        $title['title'] = 'Posts in ' . single_cat_title( '', false );
    }

    return $title;
}
```

### UPDATE

Actually, looking at the code (or ugly hack) in the *edited question*, I think my sample code above did not work because the `is_category()` returned a `false` and it's probably because the "Weekly Updates" is a Page (post of the `page` type) and not actually a default category archive at `/category/<category slug>`, e.g. `example.com/category/uncategorized`.

So let me put it this way: For themes like Twenty Sixteen which support the `title-tag`, you should use the `document_title_parts` hook to filter the title tag value, i.e. `<title>THIS PART</title>`. But as for the actual code which modifies the title, it will be up to you on how should you write your code.

Nonetheless, try this (and be sure to remove the ugly hack in your code):

```php
add_filter( 'document_title_parts', 'my_document_title_parts' );
function my_document_title_parts( $title ) {
    if ( false !== strpos( $title['title'], 'Weekly Updates' ) ) {
        $title['title'] = 'Weekly Updates';
    }

    return $title;
}
/* NOTE: Try using a greater number as the callback priority, if the default (10)
 * doesn't work - example with 9999 as the priority:
add_filter( 'document_title_parts', 'my_document_title_parts', 9999 );
*/
```

And note that the hook has one parameter which is `$title` and it's an array that consists of (but not all items present on all pages):

- **'title'**
  *(string)*  Title of the viewed page.
- **'page'**
  *(string)*  Optional. Page number if paginated.
- **'tagline'**
  *(string)*  Optional. Site description when on home page.
- **'site'**
  *(string)*  Optional. Site title when not on home page.

Also, if you want to change the title *separator* (like `-`), then you can use the [`document_title_separator` filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/document_title_separator/).

Comment: That doesn't work. I'm using Yoast. I have dug into the plug and can't see where to edit that Title tag.

Comment: Try clearing your site and browser caches, and see if the title changes. If not, then try deactivating Yoast (and/or other plugins) and see if the above filter works, because it worked for me on a default setup of WordPress with the Twenty Sixteen theme. But were you actually referring to **category** URLs like `example.com/category/some-category` and that by "2016 template", you indeed meant the Twenty Sixteen *theme*?

Comment: Or did you possibly mean a custom Page template - if so, try checking the SEO settings on the edit page screen? And if I were you, I'd try doing a grep/search in the themes and plugins directories for files containing "articles about".

Comment: Its gptta be some nonsense in Yoast, but I did a search of the code and can't find any direct matches. I ended up doing a hack which I put in the original question. It does not thrill me, but I don't know what else to do at this point.

Comment: Well, that's a seriously ugly hack. Have you tried deactivating Yoast and did my code then work? Are you sure it's a Yoast issue? If so, you should contact the author and report the issue. And you could actually try again with my code, but use a higher number as the priority: `add_filter( 'document_title_parts', 'my_document_title_parts', 9999 );`

Comment: OK, it's not Yoast. I disabled that and it persists. I'm beyond frustrated. But the hack works (for now). I just would like to get -some- explanation.

Comment: Well I can write an explanation, but could you please just try deactivating your other plugins and see if the issue persists? If **no**, activate the plugins back one at a time until the issue reappears - by then, you'd know which plugin is the culprit. PS: You can install a maintenance plugin to temporarily put the site in maintenance mode while troubleshooting the issue.

Comment: I deactivated EVERY plugin and the issue persists. -Where- exactly in 2016 is that [title] tag created?

Comment: @jchwebdev with Yoast you can set it in admin: SEO > Search Appearance > Taxonomies > (your custom taxonomy) > SEO title